# Detecting which reactive query was triggered

Tags: meteor

I have an probably not so unique issue of having a complicated meteor app.

I have several actions which are causing parts of the page to refresh which really aren't needed. But I'm having trouble locating which find() (or multiple find()'s ) is the one being triggered. I know the Collection in question, just not which find().

I could use observeChanges on every find I use, but that would be a lot of extra code.

Is there an easy way to see what is being triggered and by what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Here is a render logging function you might find useful. It logs the number of times each template is rendered to the console. You know if a template is re-rendered after initial page load, it's because a reactive data source that it relies on has changed. Either this reactive data source could have been accessed in a helper method, or the template is a list item (i.e. inside an `{{#each ...}}` block helper) and a list item was added/moved/removed/changed. Also keep in mind that child templates call their parent's rendered callback when the child is rendered or re-rendered. So, this might confuse you into thinking the parent has actually been taken off the DOM and put back, but that's not true.

So, you can call this function at the end of your client code to see the render counts:

```js
  function logRenders () {
    _.each(Template, function (template, name) {
      var oldRender = template.rendered;
      var counter = 0;

      template.rendered = function () {
        console.log(name, "render count: ", ++counter);
        oldRender && oldRender.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    });
  }
```

**EDIT**: Here is a way to wrap the find cursor to log all changes to a cursor to the console. I just wrote a similar function to this for a new package I'm working on called reactive-vision. Hopefully released soon.

```js
var wrappedFind = Meteor.Collection.prototype.find;

Meteor.Collection.prototype.find = function () {
  var cursor = wrappedFind.apply(this, arguments);
  var collectionName = this._name;

  cursor.observeChanges({
    added: function (id, fields) {
      console.log(collectionName, 'added', id, fields);
    },

    changed: function (id, fields) {
      console.log(collectionName, 'changed', id, fields);
    },

    movedBefore: function (id, before) {
      console.log(collectionName, 'movedBefore', id, before);
    },

    removed: function (id) {
      console.log(collectionName, 'removed', id);
    }
  });

  return cursor;
};
```

Comment: Cool, this is very helpful. Is there a way to see which helper, or list item actually generated the template rebuild?

Comment: I think my overall question might be, is there a way to turn on something like observeChanges globally? without having to set it up on each find.

Comment: I'd have to think about a way to do it. You'd have to get creative.

Comment: funny, yesterday i was trying to think if it was possible to update the prototype of the Collection object to do this. nice!

Comment: Somehow I am not able to get this working in my leaderboard application. I get error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined". Seems like I am not placing the call to the logRenders() at the appropriate place, but I am not clear where exactly to put it. I have currently put it at the last of the block: "if (Meteor.isClient) {"

Comment: A plnkr or fiddle would be really helpful.

Comment: Instead of _.each, it worked with $.each... even though I had the Underscore package added to my meteor app.

Comment: Since the ```rendered``` callback is only called once per template in the most recent version of meteor, the ```logRenders``` function doesn't work anymore as expected. I can't find some kind of "rerendered" callback, does somebody have an idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @cmather for the idea.

Her is `Meteor 1.3` adapted and more advanced version of `logRenders`

```js
// Log all rendered templates
// If filter is set, only templates in filter will be logged
// @params filter - name or names of template to filter
logRenders = function logRenders (filter) {
  for (name in Object(Template)){
    if (filter && !Array.isArray(filter)) filter = [filter];
    var template = Template[name];
    if (!template) continue;
    if (filter && filter.indexOf(name) == -1){
      // Clear previous logRenders
      if ('oldRender' in template) template.rendered = template.oldRender;
      delete template.oldRender;
      continue;
    }
    var t = function(name, template){
      if (!('oldRender' in template)) template.oldRender = template.rendered;
      var counter = 0;
      template.rendered = function () {
        console.log(name, ++counter, this);
        this.oldRender && this.oldRender.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    }(name, template);
  };
};
```